# How do I make this link tag in HAML?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

How can I do something like this in HAML (within Rails app such that it matters)?

```
<li><a href="#" title="Meet the Team"><strong>Team <em>16 members</em></strong></a></li>
```

**Edit**: how also to do it with `link_to` and a route of `pages_team`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
%li= link_to raw('<strong>Team <em>16 members</em></strong>'), pages_team, :title => 'Meet the Team'
```

or

```
%li= link_to content_tag(:strong, raw("Team #{content_tag(:em, '16 members)}")), pages_team, :title => 'Meet the Team
```

Answer (score 40):

The basic method would look like this ...

```
%li
  %a{ :href => "#", :title => "Meet the Team" }
    %strong
      Team
      %em 16 members
```

Or using the new hash syntax ...

```
%li
  %a{ href: "#", title: "Meet the Team" }
    %strong
      Team
      %em 16 members
```

Comment: Also note that you can supply attributes either through `{}` containing Ruby code or simply `()` containing HTML markup. `%a(href="#" title="Meet the Team")` will also work.

Comment: thanks! helpful! both of you! please see my edit...which i should have added to original question.

Comment: Note that (per its own documentation) Haml is generally intended for _structural_ markup. As @Unixmonkey has shown, it's usually easier and preferable to just drop into raw HTML when producing non-structural content markup.

Answer (score 7):

I believe the best way to do this is:

```
%li
  = link_to "#" do
    Meet the team
    %strong
      Team
      %em 16 members
```

Using haml and rails syntax together

Answer (score 0):

There is a very simple method available in Haml and Rails, here it is:

```
= link_to "hyperlink name", hyperlink_path
```

Comment: This is not the answer the asker wants I guess?